How to return the error in JSON format instead of HTML in REST framework?
I want to make an error handler exception to return the error 404 instead of this html. how can i do this ?

i tried the following code but it didn't work for me
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from django.http import Http404

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    # Call the default exception handler first,
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    # Now add the HTTP 404 handling
    if isinstance(exc, Http404):
        custom_response_data = { "error": "page not found" }
        return Response(custom_response_data, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    # Return the default response if the exception handled is not a Http404
    return response



Have you added your custom exception handler to your settings.py file? REST_FRAMEWORK = {     'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'app.exceptions.custom_exception_handler' }

@ZackTurner yes, i already added it and it did not work.

Read the last line of the first immage. It explains how to disable this page.

if you raise a Http404 error raise Http404 in a view your exception handler should return your custom JSON message

I create same things it's working fine for me
directory path (myapp/custom_exception.py)
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler


def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)
    if response.status_code == 404:
        response.data = {
            "success": False,
            "message": "Not found❗",
            "data": {}
        }
        return response
    elif response.status_code == 500:
        response.data = {
            "success": False,
            "message": "Internal server error! ",
            "data": {}
        }
    # elif response.status_code == 400:
    #     response.data = {
    #         "success": False,
    #         "message": "Bad request!",
    #         "data": {}
    #     }
    elif response.status_code == 401:
        response.data = {
            "success": False,
            "message": "Login required! ️",
            "data": {}
        }
    elif response.status_code == 403:
        response.data = {
            "success": False,
            "message": "Permission denied!",
            "data": {}
        }

    return response

settings.py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],

    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': [
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ],

    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'myapp.custom_exception.custom_exception_handler',
}

